# duplicate meta description even though link is removed?

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content, meta-description

I thought this was just webmaster taking it time to catch up but it has been there for weeks now and webmaster crawled as recently as 16th May. I am being advised in HTML improvements the below but I changed the URL on the page from:

`/ca​tal​og/​pla​nt/​con​cre​te-​pre​par​ati​on/` to `/ca​tal​og/​too​ls/​con​cre​te-​pre​par​ati​on/`

So I cannot see why it is still alerting me?

*Pages with duplicate meta descriptions*

www.contractorshire.co.uk/ca​tal​og/**​pla​nt**/​con​cre​te-​pre​par​ati​on/

www.contractorshire.co.uk/ca​tal​og/​**too​ls**/​con​cre​te-​pre​par​ati​on/

Answer (score 2):

Both: `/ca​tal​og/​pla​nt/​con​cre​te-​pre​par​ati​on/` and `/ca​tal​og/​too​ls/​con​cre​te-​pre​par​ati​on/` are accessible and I can confirm but have the same meta description and same content which Google will not like. If `/ca​tal​og/​too​ls/​con​cre​te-​pre​par​ati​on/` is the new page then you need to do a 301 redirect from the old page to that page. The old page should redirect and be inaccessible - Fix this and then Google will update ;)